# question about how i can make a slideshow with an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, slideshow, src

i would to ask you, is this an array on JS:

```
let slides = [
  {
    "image": "slide1.jpg",
    "tagLine": "Impressions tous formats <span>en boutique et en ligne</span>"
  },
  {
    "image": "slide2.jpg",
    "tagLine": "Tirages haute définition grand format <span>pour vos bureaux et events</span>"
  },
  {
    "image": "slide3.jpg",
    "tagLine": "Grand choix de couleurs <span>de CMJN aux pantones</span>"
  },
  {
    "image": "slide4.png",
    "tagLine": "Autocollants <span>avec découpe laser sur mesure</span>"
  }
];
```

If yes, how can i use it on my js code?
PS: I have the "slides" on my laptop and the srx is "./assets/images/slideshow/"

I want to do a slideshow with this images "slide1, 2, 3 and 4 but i couldn't

Comment: [Simple slideshows with captions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+simple+slideshow+with+captions)

Answer (score 0):

```
const container = document.createElement('div');
container.classList.add('image-slider');

const img = document.createElement('img');
img.classList.add('image-slider-image');
img.src = slides[0];

const prevButton = document.createElement('button');
prevButton.classList.add('image-slider-button');
prevButton.textContent = 'Previous';
const nextButton = document.createElement('button');
nextButton.classList.add('image-slider-button');
nextButton.textContent = 'Next';

container.appendChild(prevButton);
container.appendChild(img);
container.appendChild(nextButton);
document.body.appendChild(container);

prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const currentIndex = slides.indexOf(img.src);
  const newIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + slides.length) % slides.length;
  img.src = slides[newIndex];
});
nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const currentIndex = slides.indexOf(img.src);
  const newIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % slides.length;
  img.src = slides[newIndex];
});
```

Then add css for classes image-slider,image-slider-image, image-slider-button as you like.